# Importando dados de uma página da web para o Excel via VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

É o seguinte: Encontrei o código na internet que funciona perfeitamente com o que está indicando, porém preciso adaptá-lo para um projeto e não estou conseguindo.

Resumindo, a macro acessa a página http://www.namb.org, verifica o formulário de pesquisa de membros, utiliza a listbox (onde mostra os estados) como parâmetro de pesquisa (dos vários campos que possui), retorna uma tabela com as informações solicitadas e importa para a PLAN1 do Excel. Eu só precisaria trocar, no lugar de usar a listbox (Estados), usar a textbox(First Name) do formulário. Mas não consigo de jeito nenhum... poderiam me ajudar?

Segue o código prontinho:

```
   Sub extractTablesData()
 'we define the essential variables

 Dim IE As Object, obj As Object
 Dim myState As String
 Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, t As Integer
 Dim elemCollection As Object


 'add the "Microsoft Internet Controls" reference in your VBA Project indirectly
 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

 'more variables for the inputboxes - makes our automation program user friendly

 myState = InputBox("Enter the city where you wish to work")

 With IE

 .Visible = True
 .navigate ("https://www.namb.org")

 ' we ensure that the web page downloads completely before we fill the form automatically
 While IE.ReadyState <> 4
 DoEvents
 Wend

'accessing the ListBox wit States data
For Each obj In IE.Document.All.Item("csSB_Search_State").Options

        If obj.innerText = myState Then

            obj.Selected = True

        End If

    Next obj

 ' accessing the button

 IE.Document.getElementsByName("Search").Item.Click

 ' again ensuring that the web page loads completely before we start scraping data
 Do While IE.busy: DoEvents: Loop

'Clearing any unnecessary or old data in Sheet1
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K500").ClearContents

 Set elemCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")

    For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 1)

        For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
            For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
            Next c
        Next r
    Next t

 End With

 ' cleaning up memory
 Set IE = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Acredito que preciso fazer a mudança no trecho abaixo, mas já tentei de (quase) tudo e não consigo:

```
For Each obj In IE.Document.All.Item("csSB_Search_State").Options

        If obj.innerText = myState Then

            obj.Selected = True

        End If

    Next obj
```

Answer (score 4):

Só precisa substituir o o bloco do `for` que vc marcou por isso:

```
IE.document.getelementbyid("csSB_Search_FirstName_ID").Value = myState
```

Usei a mesma variavel `MyState` pra não complicar mto, mas você pode alterar se quiser.

Provavelmente essa pergunta já era, mas deixa a resposta aqui pra futuras consultas né.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Talvez você possa me ajudar com este problema: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644769/how-to-use-getelementsbytagname-with-td-with-overflow-hidden-on-vba